# ¿Cómo explicitar una condición de desigualdad de NAN al usar if?

Tags: python

Lo que necesito hacer es bastante simple: 
Necesito que al hacer un "if", python me cumpla la condición solo para aquellos valores que son distintos de "nan". Pero no me está funcionando. He intentado:

```
if df['var']!= 'nan':
    ax1.text(df['var'],0,'',  horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='bottom')
```

Todo esto está dentro de una definición para hacer un gráfico. df es un data frame donde los "nan" están ya como int.

Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano, saludos

Comment: Que tipo de valor es?

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values) revisa este enlace

Comment: `pd.isna(serie)` devuelve otra serie con true donde había nan, y false donde no, que puedes usar como filtro en un data frame. Para la condición contraria `~pd.isna(serie)`

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar la función `numpy.isnan(array)` para obtener un vector **booleano**.

Notar que en el pedazo de código que muestras, al hacer `df['var']` estás obteniendo un objeto `Series`, que corresponde a un iterable de las filas de la columna `var`. 
Por lo tanto, el uso de la función `numpy.isnan` debería ser algo así:

```
selection = df['var']  # shape (#_de_filas, )
nans = numpy.isnan(selection)  # vector de booleanos: True si es NaN, False si ~
```

Lamentablemente, uno no puede hacer:

```
if numpy.isnan(selection): 
  # do something
```

Dado que `np.isnan(selection)` retorna un arreglo de booleanos, por lo que se debe reducir a un solo valor booleano: *True o False*.

Comunmente las condicionales de una reducción de este vector se hace mediante las operaciones `.any()` y `all()`. Y tienen el siguiente comportamiento:

```
if numpy.isnan(selection).any():
  print('existe al menos un NaN en selection')
if numpy.isnan(selection).all():
  print('todos los elementos son NaN en selection')
```

Para la mayoría de los casos alguno de esos métodos basta. Si ya necesitas un comportamiento *ad-hoc* deberías hacer tu propia función que se encargue de checkear acorde a tus necesidades y que retorne un único booleano.